# Illegal Configuration: Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported

Tags: storyboard, xcode9-beta

I recently updated to **XCode 9**. When I build the app it says **"illegal configuration"** for some storyboards in my pod files. I tried to recreate the storyboard files but it doesn't help.

[image: [1]]

Comment: Yet another reason not to use xib files.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

XCode 9 will not support storyboards that are built for iOS version less than 7.

Try changing the **Builds for** in **File Inspector** to a higher version then Clean and Build.

See screenshot

[image]

Edit: Important info from @user435779 below: Restart XCode if the errors don't go away.

Comment: I highly recommend setting **Builds for** to `Deployment Target (v.m)` *(make sure your target is 7+)*

Comment: I found I also needed to close and restart XCode after doing the Clean.  No idea why.  ymmv

Comment: @user435779 You were right, restarting did the trick. Clean then restart. Also, it works if you actually open all your xib files, one by one, and setting the Deployment Target manually, if not already set. Then clean and restart.

Comment: I had a bunch of xib files so changing each build for would have been a small challenge, but simply changing the Deployment Target worked fine for me. For laughs, it was set to 6.1! Lol.

Comment: I had a few random XIBs set to 7.x - no idea why. Thank you @user435779 - I needed to restart XCode to make it work. I'll add that to the main answer.

Comment: I cannot find "File Inspector" anywhere in "Xcode 9". Could you please provide a larger screenshot showing how to get there?

Comment: @DJGruby Please check this screenshot https://screencast.com/t/Eaf1olBCp

Comment: I recommend that you choose the deployment target iOS version.

Comment: Don't know why but always restart the XCode does the Job.!

Answer (score 32):

Simply set the deployment target to 8.0 + in **General** to fix this issue. No need to go through each xib file.

[image]

Comment: You set the target to 7.0, you would not have issues too! So if you want lower deployment target 7.0 is the lowest possible to avoid this Illegal Configuration issue.

Comment: got error "This application does not support this device’s CPU type"

Comment: Even though the `Deployment Target` is set under `General`, the xib files can independently have their `File Inspector` -> `Interface Builder Document` section set to a separate `Builds for` setting that does not follow the `General` setting. This is especially true when you are re-using "code" or xib files across projects or from open source.

Comment: Thank you - I needed to open an old project and Xcode was beach-balling as soon as I tried to open the Storyboard to change the deployment target. Changing the Deployment Target for the whole project was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 14):

As storyboard in Xcode 9 will not support which is below iOS 7.0, so you need to update the iOS version in **File inspector**.

For more information please find the below GIF representation.

[image]

Hope it works!!!

Comment: Excuse me, Can I know how you made or what stuff you used for that GIF animation in your MacOS?

Comment: Download the "Giphy Capture" software from the AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both methods - On Xcode 9.3 (9E145)

For each XIB, I added the following Target.

[image]

The On Targets -> General -> Deployment Info-> Change target

[image]

Cleaned the project and build again into device. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

My case was the different, I did all the above solution but not getting succeed build, so I read the error with focus and go to manually with the file open the .Xib file and change it development target to iOS 10 and later.

and Yup.. its work Fine