# xamarin.forms: ibtool exited with code 1, Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Since, I upgraded to xCode 9 on my Mac I get the following error when compiling:

> Error     ibtool exited with code 1
>   Error       Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429415/illegal-configuration-compiling-ib-documents-for-earlier-than-ios-7-is-no-longe) I don't have a project setting in visual studio (on windows) with an option "Build for: iOS 10 and later".

Also, I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project, so I don't have any storyboards. How can I solve this issue?

[EDIT] I'm working with the Visual Studio IDE on Windows. I use the mac only for building the iOS Apps.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that your deployment target in info.plist is set to 6.0.  Set it to at least 7.0 and you will be fine.

Comment: My Deployment target is set to 8.0 and I still get this issue.
This is what solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429415/illegal-configuration-compiling-ib-documents-for-earlier-than-ios-7-is-no-longe/44430034#44430034

Answer (score 2):

I am going to *assume* that you have an older `LaunchScreen.storyboard` within your `Xamarin.iOS` application project.

I do not know how to edit those setting within the VS4M Storyboard editor, so right click on the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and open it with the `Xcode Interface Builder`.

In the right-hand column, the `File Inspector` should be the default view, change it as shown in the SO answer that you linked:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430034/4984832

Do a `File` / `Save`, exit Xcode, and do a **clean** and re-build your solution. I had to do this with a couple of old `Xamarin.Forms` solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue.
You just go to storyboard, Interface Builder Document -> choose a version build for.
That fix my issue.
Goodluck!
interface

[image]